# All vapors are in the gas phase. Is my understanding correct?

Tags: phase-transition

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/vapor) defines "vapor" as

> gas or extremely small drops of liquid that result from the heating of a liquid or solid

which seems incorrect, because all vapors are in the gas phase. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: What aspect seems incorrect?

Comment: Their definition for “steam” refers to a white cloud. Clearly these are colloquial—as opposed to technical—definitions.

Comment: Check out https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapor#Properties

Comment: Definitions can be tricky and generally require context. Oxford’s, for example, has definitions for vapor in the categories. All, Physics, Chemistry and Medicine. The physics definition is similar to Wikipedias.